# TypeError using custom template tag

Tags: django

I get `'module' object is not callable` using the following template tag:

`projectname/controlpanel/templatetags/__init__.py` (blank file)

`projectname/controlpanel/templatetags/md_to_html.py`

```
from django import template
from markdown import markdown

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='to_html')
def to_html(md):
    return markdown(md)
```

In one of my views, I return `{'campaign': campaign}`, with `campaign` being an instance of a model with a `description` TextField.

```
<div class="span8" id="editor2">
   {{ selected_campaign.description|to_html }}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you loading the module inside the template? {% load %} tag? Also, can you post the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: Please as @PauloBu says post the full traceback

Comment: Yes, I have `{% load md_to_html %}` placed at the top of my template. Traceback: https://gist.github.com/randallm/51d34b2ee0c7768d6734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to INSTALLED_APPS

```
'django.contrib.markup',
```

copy markdown(http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) to your django project directory

then use

```
{% load markup %}
<div class="span8" id="editor2">
      {{ selected_campaign.description|markdown:"safe" }}
</div>
```

---

### Update:

#### `django.contrib.markup` is deprecated in Django 1.5. Here is a simple replacement for the markdown filter.

remove line `'django.contrib.markup',` from `INSTALLED_APPS`

steps to create a template tag:

- add a folder `templatetags` in any of your `app` folder.
- inside `templatetags` folder add an empty file `__init__.py`

add `markup.py` inside `templatetags` with these codes:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import markdown as mkdn

register = template.Library()     
@register.filter
def markdown(value,smode=None):
    return mark_safe(mkdn.markdown(value, safe_mode='escape'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not why but `markdown` seems does not work inside a function in django for example I typed this in django shell (python manage.py shell):

```
from markdown import markdown

def yes():
     return markdown("YES")
```

and it gives me the next error:

```
NameError: global name 'markdown' is not defined
```

and this seems to work

```
def yes():
     from markdown import markdown
     return markdown("YES")
```

outside django shell the first method works correctly hope this helps!